# The ICU library support cannot be enabled on linux

Tags: linux, qt, redhat

I'm building the Qt 5.5.0 on red hat Linux with the ICU support as below `./configure -debug -opensource -confirm-license -c++11 -force-debug-info -arch linux-x86_64 -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-zlib -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-xcb -icu -opengl -prefix $PWD/deployment`. But the config end up with `The ICU library support cannot be enabled on linux`. 
I found this [link](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2016-0781.html) which lists the packages for icu but could not install them with `# yum install libicu-devel`. Do I need to link to any repository for successfully installing the ICU. or shed some lights on how to resolve this dependency to resolve the error `The ICU library support cannot be enabled`.

Note: I want QT to be built with ICU support.

Comment: "But could not install them with yum install..." - why not? Any distro shipping KDE/Qt should come with a sufficient libicu.

Comment: When I run the below command it looks like the libicu is installed but not sure why I get `The ICU library support cannot be enabled`.

Comment: `[root@Linux 5.5.0]# yum install libicu-4.2.1-12.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
Package matching libicu-4.2.1-12.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do`

Comment: `You are also licensed to use this software under the terms of
the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) versions 3.

You have already accepted the terms of the Open Source license.
Creating qmake...
.Done.
Running configuration tests...
**The ICU library support cannot be enabled.**
 Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to /home/panch/Downloads/build/Qt/5.5.0/qtbase/configure to see the final report.
 If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue`

Comment: You also need to install the -devel package

Comment: The following execution on terminal reports no package available `# yum install libicu-devel` `# yum install libicu-devel-4.2.1-14.el6.x86_64`. Am I missing any repo reference in my machine. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I figured out to fix this issue as follows, instead of trying to use `yum install <package>` I downloaded the RPM `libicu-devel-4.2.1-14.el6.x86_64.rpm` from this `[link][1]`. Now I'm able to run configure without aforementioned error.